# Find any repetitive words in files using egrep

Tags: regex, grep, command, backreference

Here is my command line:

```
grep -E "(\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}\b)(.*)\1"
```

and I'm getting this:

```
meilleure allo meilleure
mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss
mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss
mota6l yolo mota6l
mota7ll yolo mota7ll
meilleure allo meilleure
mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss
```

But I need to have only the words that are at least six characters, but repeated more than three times. I've tried backreferences, without success. Any tips on the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use quantifier for the repetition grouping

```
$ # more than 2 times
$ grep -E '(\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}\b)(.*\b\1\b){2,}' ip.txt 
mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss
mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss
$ # more than 3 times
$ grep -E '(\b[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}\b)(.*\b\1\b){3,}' ip.txt 
mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss a mota20lettressssssss
```